# What is the impact when purchasing a competitor domain?

Tags: domains, ranking, google-ranking

I have a website for designers of wedding invites. They show their work on the site. Where my goal is to send as much traffic as I can to the designers websites. In return the pay me for their spot on the website. In Dutch it's called a *vergelijkingssite*.

I have the chance to purchase the domain of one of my competitors. This is a site with about 100 pages ranked in google. They asked me what I want to offer for the domain.

Before I decide this I was wondering, does it have any impact good or bad on my ranking if I purchase this domain. Add it to my main domain as domain pointer. And then redirect all ranked pages of the purchased domain to similar pages on my own website?

A bit more information about the domain name I want to purchase, because it once was the place to go to when you wanted a wedding invite. It has more links pointing to it and a better domain authority (Moz) then my domain has.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Zeba This is pretty commonly done. It could help to increase your traffic and build authority if done properly. See this question as to [how](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77700/how-can-i-use-a-competitors-domain-that-i-purchased?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Google [Penguin](https://searchengineland.com/library/google/google-penguin-update) may pick that up and destroy the SEO rank for both sites. Why not move to that domain? It already has a high authority ranking with backlinks you can't that you can't change. Sure you can redirect the page it links to, but the physical anchor tag with their domain name on the linking page will be collected by Google to boost the authority of your competitor's domain. Another option is to link to your website on several of their pages, but I don't think redirecting all their pages to yours is a good idea. It looks to similar to buying an SEO score.

Answer (score 1):

> I have the chance to purchase the domain of one of my competitors.
>   This is a site with about 100 pages ranked in google. They asked me
>   what I want to offer for the domain.

I would ask for traffic stats. If they are hosting the domain name, they may be able to provide raw webserver logs. Then you analyze the files, try to figure out the volume and the quality, something that is not straightforward. Then present a monetary offer based on projected benefits.

If the data is not available, you can still ask for a traffic test. Just ask the other party to change the DNS settings and point to a webserver you control, and collect some stats for a while.
This could be a bargaining chip too: if there is no data about the traffic you are 'obliged' to make a conservative offer.

What about the domain itself ?

Assume the domain name is average or mediocre, then the value comes from the traffic only.
On the other hand, if the domain name is of a generic nature, then there are some advantages in terms of branding, advertising etc. All things being equal, a memorable domain name is better than some made-up mix of letters.